# curl connection is working on localhost but connection refused error on live server

Tags: php, curl

This is working fine on localhost

```
$url ="http://23.254.128.22:9080/urldreamclient/dreamurl?userName=XXXXX&password=XXXXX&clientid=XXXXX&to=".$number."&text=".$smstxt."&Senderid=XXXX";

$ch = curl_init($url);    // initialize curl handle
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($ch);
```

but showing error on live server

**Failed to connect to 23.254.128.22 port 9080: Connection refused**

So there is any problem with hosting server?

Comment: Check server fire wall settings

Comment: Is it a free hosting server? Those usually have a heavily restricted firewall setup which won't allow connections on "rare" ports

Comment: its paid, godaddy managed wordpress hosting. So i h've no cpanel access in this package..

Comment: Hi, did u found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely not.

I have the same problem and it's because my SSH machine is not same machine as the HTTP server.

Try running **netstat -tulpn | grep 9080** from SSH and also through PHP from your browser. Your SSH session should obviously see port 9080 being open, but your browser should not.

My temporary solution is to start my "9080" through making a request to a PHP script (so it's definitely running on the HTTP machine), which starts my "9080" server in the background (**nohup /path1/path2/start9080.sh > /dev/null 2> /dev/null &**). Then my PHP scripts can hit "9080".

Problems with this method are that

- starting and stopping "9080" goes through public "api" (clearly dangerous)
- "9080" can't be accessed publicly (exactly what I want)
- "9080" sometimes gets killed (???)